# Best circuit for Zero Cross Detection

Tags: pwm, dimming

I am trying to build an optimal circuit for Zero cross detection for PWM dimming using a microcontroller. I have gone through most of forums and their implementation varies.

I understand that the easiest option is to use an AC optocoupler with few resistors to connect to AC and then feed it to the microcontroller for zero cross detection. I have also tried that myself using Sharp PC814 and found working, however it gives slight flickering at low dim levels. (My input is 240V, 50Hz). The resistors also becomes hot despite using 1/4 watt x 4 connected in series ( 2x22K + 2x50K ) giving a total of 1W.

The other option suggested is to use a rectifier and then feed to a normal optocoupler. Does this solution have an advantage over the above solution of using an AC optocoupler directly ?

I have also found another forum suggesting two optocouplers in the reverse direction and feed their output(2 outputs) to a microcontroller. Again these has to be handled separately to find out zero cross. What benefits would this give ?

I have also seen forums suggesting a transformer, but I think an opto can do the job well considering the size, cost and efficiency.

Moreover I have referred one commercial boards and found it using a rectifier and an AC opto (H11AA1) which seems to be unnecessary since the opto itself can handle AC. However it gave smooth dimming at all levels (compared to the one I have build in the same AC source).

I would appreciate if someone can help me to identify the optimal solutions to find zero cross factoring the spikes, noise and some times the square wave from an inverter in the source. I understand that some programming would be necessary to make it better, however I want to ensure the circuit is good enough to handle most cases.

Comment: Do you understand cause of flicker fault?  false trigger , or not strong enough gate current? We can only guess. My favorite ZCS pulse is CMOS XOR gate with delay of xx μs on one side.

Comment: It seems to be false trigger when I check through the program and it varies a lot, which makes me believe that it could be due to the noise or spikes in the supply current. I don't have a scope to confirm anyway. Moreover the other board which uses rectifier and H11AA1 works fine in the same supply.

Comment: A big clue is the pulse width. But if you cant measure this, then you must vary the collector R value by a large tolerance (> 50%) and compare results.  Start with 20K and go down to failure.

Comment: You mean 20K for the connecting 240VAC to optocoupler ? And 'go down to failure' means ? Reducing 20K may damage the optocoupler

Comment: No I meant the DC side,  collector Rc, What is your value of Rc?  This controls the voltage gain  while the current gain spec is 0.2 to 2 or 20% to 200% CTR. But after considering LPF effect of raising Rc value while increasing gain, I think Rc ought to be 200k.  some calc's needed.

Comment: The optocoupler output is connected to the GPIO using a 1K resistor (source is 3.3v) and the same GPIO is pulled down using 10K. I am not using any filters as it may affect the zero cross detection.

Comment: why would you choose those R values so low?  If you raise the pullup x10 then you will have fewer issues.  Why pulldown?

Comment: I have set the zero cross detection using the rising interrupt inside my code. Hence the gpio is pulled down normally and is raised only when the opto coupler is active. I have selected the 1K resistance referring to some sample schematics for the MCU. Do you think that the flickering would stop by changing these values ? Appreciate if you can brief about it. Also. is this the best approach for commercial boards ?

Comment: Zero crossing detection.  More info: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/428750/zero-crossing-signal-timing/454661#454661